# Bind several Inputs to OnKeyPress event

Tags: jquery, events, bind

I have several inputs, they are created dynamically

```
<input style="width:100%" class="fileDescription" type="text" name="' + descriptionId + '" id="' + descriptionId + '" placeholder="Write a file description, hit Enter to save" />
```

I would like to attach KeyPress event to all these Inputs and pass ID of the Input. How to do that? I have tried to use code below to attach event but that does not work. Also I do not know how to pass ID of the Input field to the binded event.

```
  $('.fileDescription').bind('keypress', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Works!");

            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.fileDescription').live('keypress', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.id);
});
```

You'll see in the jsfiddle example how the 2nd element that was added dynamically also works.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nduYR/3/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.fileDescription').bind('keydown', function(e) {        
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly for me...

http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/f6urc/

Comment: but it is not created dinamically. ;)

Comment: Well, I would argue that the validity of your statement depends on how you define "Created Dynamically". My code certainly could have been created dynamically by PHP. If you're talking about JS doing the work, then you are correct and using `.live()` would be the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [live functionality](http://api.jquery.com/live/), when dealing with dynamic content.

```
$(".fileDescription").live("keydown", function ()
{
   // ...
});
```